# Log every file that a process accesses

Tags: audit

I want to be able to take a process on a Linux machine and log every file that it opens, reads, or writes during a certain time window.

For example, let's say that I suspect that Apache is using an incorrect file for some reason. How could I run the request that triggers the file open/read and then get a list of every file that was opened by the Apache process in order to debug it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strace is one way that comes to mind.

This answer discusses it in greater detail:

[Can strace show me the filename/path for read/write syscalls](https://serverfault.com/questions/727555/can-strace-show-me-the-filename-path-for-read-write-syscalls/727647#727647)

Answer (score 0):

Auditd is built for this purpose.  You can create simple rules to log specific forms of access by uid, gid, (greater or less than uid/gid), directory, filesystem, etc.